# fadeIn() display first and then fade

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseevent

i am doing a fixed menu wich has a tool tip, when you do mouse over on on on of the items it should appear an immage doing a fadeIn() but the behavor is so weird that it appears first and then makes the fade in i amm not sure what is this happening ill leave you the code to see if someone could explain me what is happening and also help me, i amm learning and i will appreciate it too much!.

HTML

```
<div id="nav-pPal">
  <ul class="nav-Ppal">
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"></div>
      <a class="btns-nav" id="0" href="#block-intro">01</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"></div>
      <a class="btns-nav" id="1" href="#block-pq-zolfunza">02</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"></div>
      <a class="btns-nav" id="2" href="#block-modulos-zolfunza">03</a>    
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"></div>
      <a class="btns-nav" id="3" href="#block-seguridad">04</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"></div>
      <a class="btns-nav" id="4" href="#block-desarrollo">05</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"></div>
      <a class="btns-nav" id="5" href="#block-nuestra-ubic">06</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"></div>
      <a class="btns-nav" id="6" href="#block-noticias">07</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"></div>
      <a class="btns-nav" id="7" href="#block-preguntas">08</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="tooltip"></div>
      <a class="btns-nav" id="8" href="#block-contacto">09</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

THIS IS THE CSS

```
#nav-pPal {
width:30px;
height:auto;
position:fixed;
right:0;
top:30%;
z-index:5;
}

.nav-Ppal li a {
width: 30px;
height: 22px;
padding-top:8px;
text-align:center;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
cursor:pointer;
background-color: #000;
color: #FFF;
opacity: 1;
-moz-opacity: 0.70;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=70);
cursor:pointer;
font-family: 'lucida_sans_unicoderegular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
}



.tooltip{
background: black;
display: none;
height: 140px;
position: absolute;
right: 32px;
width: 200px;
transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

FINNALLY THE JQUERY
    //------------tool tip main menu ------------

```
$(".btns-nav").on("mouseover", displayPreview);

function displayPreview(){
    $(this).prev().fadeIn("slow");
    console.log(this);
}

$(".btns-nav").on("mouseleave", hiePreview);

function hidePreview(){
    $(this).prev().fadeOut("slow");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this CSS line:

```
transition: all .2s ease;
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTSe4/7/

Comment: still not working, i just found that was a problem with the css because i had the transition: all .2 ease then it was behaving weird...thank you anyways! [edit] I posted this before you editted your comment....thank you! is working right now!

Answer (score 0):

Hide all the other tooltips and then show the hovered one:

```
$(".tooltip").hide();
$(this).prev().fadeIn("slow");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gRPnP/1/